# Auto-increment the value only when the value of another column changes sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have this (SQL server) database, sorted by value A and value B should be incremented only when the value A gets change:

BillNo         Value B
SC-P1100           1
SC-P1100             1  BillNo  changes
SC-blb00             2  BillNo  changes
SC-P6010             3
SC-P6010            3
SC-P6010            3   BillNo  changes
SB-T1810           4

How do I select the rows in the above manner? Please answer

Thanks

Comment: Are you using [tag:sql-server] or [tag:mysql]? The content suggest the former, but the tags suggest the latter.

Comment: What is the actual data in your table?

Comment: Post your actual data in table so that I can get a way to think

Comment: Its a actual data it goes like in the same manner. i only want a auto incremented column say value B based on BillNo.. whenever the billNo changes the value B gets incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CTE to do that.

```
WITH CTE (Col1, RowNumber)
AS
(
    SELECT <YOUR_COLUMN_NAME_HERE> AS Col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) As RowNumber
    FROM <YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE>
)

SELECT Col1, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Col1)
    FROM CTE InnerCTE
    WHERE InnerCTE.RowNumber <= OuterCTE.RowNumber
) As NumberOfDistinctItemsInCol1
FROM CTE OuterCTE
```

Be sure to replace <YOUR_COLUMN_NAME_HERE> with your actual column name and <YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE> with your actual table name.

Comment: Its working.. But its kinda very slow when i am having 10k rows

Comment: Well, optimization depends on many things. You know the way your system is built, I don't. therefor you have a much better starting point for optimizing your database performance. I would start by running the query on SSMS and show the execution plan. You might want to consider adding an index you your table on BillNo column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
UPDATE tableA   
  SET BillNo='new value'
  , ValueB=ValueB+1
  WHERE BillNo='Old value';
```

Comment: thanks but i need a select query..i only want a auto incremented column say value B based on BillNo.. whenever the billNo changes the value B gets incremented in the similar fashion as shown above

Comment: you mean like this `SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY ValueB`  ?